# Multiple tables join issue in sequelize in node js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 6 tables
Employees,Salary,Deduction,DeductionTypes,Allowance,AllowancesTypes

Here is the table relations with a diagram
[image]

I can't understand how to create a join query

```
Employee.belongsTo(Salary, {  foreignKey: 'employee_id' });
Salary.belongsToMany(Deduction,    {foreignKey: 'salary_id' });
Deduction.belongsToMany(DeductionType,    {foreignKey:   'deduction_type_id' });
Salary.belongsToMany(Allowance,    {foreignKey: 'salary_id' });
Allowance.belongsToMany(AllowanceType,    {foreignKey: 'allowance_type_id' });
```

Here is my find query

```
const payRunData = Employee.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Salary, attributes: ['salary_id', 'basic_salary'],
        include: [
            {
                model: Deduction, attributes: ['amount'],
                include: [{
                    model: DeductionType, attributes: ['epf_enable', 'type', 'pre_tax', 'pay_run_editable'],
                }]
            },
            {
                model: Allowance, attributes: ['amount'],
                include: [{
                    model: AllowanceType, attributes: ['epf_enable', 'type', 'payee_enable', 'pay_run_editable'],
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
    ],
    attributes: ['employee_id', 'given_names'],
});
```

Here is the sql join query what I'm expecting

```
select s.salary_id , e.employee_id, e.given_names, d.amount as 'deduction_amount',
dty.`type` as 'deduction_type', dty.epf_enable as 'deductType_epf_enable', dty.pre_tax, dty.pay_run_editable as 'deductType_pay_run_editable',
a.amount as 'allowance_amount', aty.`type`as 'allowanceType_type', aty.epf_enable as 'allowanceType_epf_enable',
aty.payee_enable  as 'allowanceType_payee', aty.pay_run_editable as 'allowanceType_pay_run_editable'
from employees as e inner join salary as s on e.employee_id = s.salary_id
inner join deductions as d on  s.salary_id = d.salary_id
inner join deduction_types as dty on d.deduction_type_id = dty.deduction_type_id
inner join allowances as a on  s.salary_id = a.salary_id
inner join allowance_types as aty on a.allowance_type_id = aty.allowance_type_id
```

When I execute this,it's returning this error

> salary.belongsToMany(deduction) requires through option, pass either a
> string or a model"

please help me  to solve this

Comment: what is the problem -- did you not get what you are expecting?

Comment: @Hogan,
it returns this error,
salary.belongsToMany(deduction) requires through option, pass either a string or a model"

Comment: @SupunAravinda, I think the problem is with the associations you declared, try `hasMany` instead of `belongsToMany`.

Comment: @Raja, yes you are correct.I changed the association.However thank you for your help